# Debug native Android Applications

Tags: android, eclipse

Is it possible to debug a native Android application with eclipse and the Android SDK.  I have downloaded the sources.  Would I have to build the app and then deploy it onto the device to debug it (like any other debugging process)?  If so, how would I go about doing that (can use messenger/call app if needed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can debug native android applications using eclipse and ndk-gdb. The detailed information you can find [here](http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/)